# Phone call logs in Android

Tags: android

I have a new Android phone that I purchased a few months ago directly from the company's website.

All is fine with that phone, except one thing. It occasionally makes a short phone call. That call doesn't show up in the Phone app's Call Log User Interface.

I get to know that it is  making these phone calls because I have a prepaid plan that has pretty expensive outgoing calls and for each outgoing call, I get an SMS from the provider letting me know the cost of the call (and remaining balance).

What would be the best way for me to detect where are these calls going to?  (I'm a programmer, but not an Android programmer).

I don't want to go to the service provider and ask my call history because it's a cumbersome process that involves physical visits to their far-away office(s) and I don't want to go to the Police as I don't want to submit the phone to them for investigation.

(p.s. I haven't given call permissions to many apps. Just a few well-known ones, like Banking/Payment apps, Google apps and Truecaller)

Comment: Is it possible that you're getting those messages from your operator because some app is sending a text message from your phone? Or are you completely sure that it's a phone call and not an SMS/MMS?

Comment: @pri It is a phone call and not an SMS/MMS. The message  says "your last call of duration 00:00:06 cost XXX" etc. The duration is sometimes 6 seconds, sometimes 8 seconds and so on

Comment: In later versions of Android, notifications can be logged. It also logs the notifications of ongoing calls. You could probably check in notification history if you can see some notifications of ongoing calls that you are not aware of.

Comment: I assume you have bought Pixel 6 which is making phantom calls due to a bug in Google Assistant. [Some Pixel 6 phones are reportedly ghost-dialing people](https://www.xda-developers.com/pixel-6-ghost-dialing-problem/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create your own app to log all outgoing phone calls. You can reuse the code provided on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56901676/891194) at StackOverflow. I just tried it in an emulator and it works as is. Your app will catch the called number in OutgoingCallReceiver class. You can store the phone numbers in a [shared pref](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) file or in a sqlite db to investigate later.